# Android Path internal Storage

Tags: android, sqlite, path, backup

I'm having a problem with the internal path to export the database. The Log says it is the wrong path.

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
           FileChannel source=null;
           FileChannel destination=null;
           String cartella = (getString(R.string.app_name));
           String currentDBPath = "/data/"+getPackageName()+"/cartella/"+"Backup.db";
           String backupDBPath = "/cartella/Backup.db";

           File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
           File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
           try {
                source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                source.close();
                destination.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(R.string.Toast_export_errore), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                     toast.show();
```

Log

```
01-20 08:55:14.757: W/System.err(1383): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/info.androidhive.slidingmenu/cartella/Backup.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

01-20 08:55:14.787: W/System.err(1383):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
01-20 08:55:14.787: W/System.err(1383):     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:78)
01-20 08:55:14.827: W/System.err(1383):     at main.Impostazioni.Esporta(Impostazioni.java:334)
01-20 08:55:14.827: W/System.err(1383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 08:55:14.827: W/System.err(1383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-20 08:55:14.827: W/System.err(1383):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
01-20 08:55:14.857: W/System.err(1383):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-20 08:55:14.857: W/System.err(1383):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-20 08:55:14.877: W/System.err(1383):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-20 08:55:14.877: W/System.err(1383):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-20 08:55:14.887: W/System.err(1383):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 08:55:14.898: W/System.err(1383):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-20 08:55:14.927: W/System.err(1383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 08:55:14.927: W/System.err(1383):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-20 08:55:14.957: W/System.err(1383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-20 08:55:14.957: W/System.err(1383):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-20 08:55:14.987: W/System.err(1383):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 08:55:14.987: W/System.err(1383): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: please post your logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
```

with:

```
File currentDB = getDatabasePath("Backup.db");
```

Hardcoding the database path is not a good idea since it is not guaranteed to be the same on all devices. Using getDatabasePath() will return the path on which the database was created. So if the database does exist, the correct path to it will be returned.

EDIT:

To restore a database you have previously exported, do exactly as you did for the export. The only difference is that you need to switch the source and destination around so that the source is now your backup file path and the destination is now the database file path. The database will then be overwritten with the backup:

```
source = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
destination = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
```

Comment: You can use getParent() or getParentFile() on the File returned to get the directory the database is in. Did using getDatabasePath() fix your error?

Comment: yes, getDatabasePath () is fine. but I would like some advice or a good example to import from sd card.

Comment: Please see my edit. It is a simple case of doing the copy in the reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is

> `/data/data/info.androidhive.slidingmenu/cartella/Backup.db`

a valid path?
You can use DDMS to check in your app data that `Backup.db` exist